# When to delete old entries from MySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, typo3

So I run this TYPO3 website with nearly 80 tables. TYPO3 don't delete records really, it only writes an "1" into the table field deleted to mark them. This leads to a big table with many records that are not visible in the application but have to be processed in every database query.

My question is: Until how many dead entries should you keep those entries before facing disadvantages like performance decrease? Is there any known number of entries no matter the server hardware?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Data retention period depends on the application requirements. If there are any feature, which requires to show history of records, then you have to keep history records for some time.

Comment: Thats why deleted records are just marked as deleted=1 but are still available in the backend module 'Recycler' to decide to remove completely or restore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TYPO3 has an included task to do cleanups for old/deleted entries, called:

> **Table garbage collection : cleans up old records from any table in the database.**
>   See https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-scheduler/master/en-us/Installation/BaseTasks/Index.html#table-garbage-collection-task

You may decide, which kind of entries should be cleaned in which period, depend on your use case and your server environment.

Comment: I have to add this one: it is not really true, that the data is not visible in the backend. You should use the system extension "recycler", which is a perfect way to show records which are marked as deleted, and also you will be able to restore deleted records!

Additionally I suppose a period of about 90 days before a record gets deleted permanently by the mentioned garbage collector tasks, that's my personal default most of the time, but this may vary depending on your needs.

Answer (score -1):

It depends.  If there are good indexes, the extra rows may not hurt performance much.  Are you seeing a slowdown?  (There's an old saying: "If it ain't broke, don't fix it.")

Something like `DELETE FROM t WHERE deleted` may be a viable way to clean up table `t`.  But it may run into issues with `FOREIGN KEYs`.

How many rows in the tables?  If there are millions of rows to `DELETE`, it gets tricky to do the task without bringing the system to its knees.

Comment: This answer isn't really great, as TYPO3 ships with a garbage collector and some other tasks, which can clean up the system automagically without any hassle with foreign keys etc.
There is also a task e.g. for optimizing DB tables, you could run these tasks e.g. on a daily base.